# generate barcode from alphanumeric string using python

Tags: python, barcode

How can I generate barcode in python using alphanumeric strings?
All the answers are for generating barcode using numbers only (using `barcode` package).

e.g. value : "ABC1234XYZ"

Referred https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-generate-barcode-in-python/ which talks about generating barcode in python. But a alphanumeric string cannot be used here.

Comment: *"All the answers are for generating barcode using numbers only"* then use a barcode format that isn't just for numbers.

Answer (score 1):

From Python-barcode documentation, it states that it support different barcode type, including Code39 & Code128 etc which support alphanumeric values

https://python-barcode.readthedocs.io/en/stable/